# How wide is one's pee stream on the Moon?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, gravity, water

This morning it occurred to me that on the Moon, with one-sixth of Earth's gravity, your pee stream should be wider, because you're peeing at the same rate, but there is weaker gravity to stretch it downwards into a stream. Rather than a thin stream it might look more like a thick rope of pee. So I'm wondering, how thick?

I found no answer online, although according to https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/003325.htm, the average "flow rate" is:

> Ages 4 to 7 — males 10 mL/sec, females 10 mL/sec.
>   Ages 8 to 13 — males 12 mL/sec, females 15 mL/sec.
>   Ages 14 to 45 — males 21 mL/sec, females 18 mL/sec.
>   Ages 46 to 65 — males 12 mL/sec, females 18 mL/sec.
>   Ages 66 to 80 — males 9 mL/sec, females 18 mL/sec.

So 10 to 20 mL/sec is typical.

Lunar gravity, according to https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/moonfact.html is 1.62 m/s².

But I do not know how to put these numbers together to calculate the diameter of the flow. I'm worried it requires understanding of water surface tension and other things beyond my maths ability. Can anyone shine some light?

Comment: It will boil explosively.

Comment: Ask Buzz Aldrin.......the first man to perform this tricky operation, but inside a spacesuit......ahhhh the glamour of being an astronaut..

Comment: @CountIblis Inside a room I mean, obviously.

Comment: I think it doesn't really depends on the gravity, it depends on the pressure of the urinary bladder.

Comment: @peterh Then assume peeing horizontally.

Comment: I'm surprised and depressed by the reaction to this question. I thought it would generate interesting and insightful discussion. I especially don't understand the grouchy closure reason. "Specific physics concept" -- the effect of gravitational strength on the dynamics of a falling water stream sounds physicsy to me. Should I have used bigger words? "Show some effort" -- I'm sorry but I don't know the maths! I never got to finish school. I researched some numbers at least. I'm planning to wait one year, ask this question again, and just hope to encounter people who are less sour about it.

Comment: I think they found your question as a homework task, while it clearly isn't. Maybe they've found the question nonsense, too. I voted your question up, as an interesting and funny one, and initiated a reopen vote. Unfortunately, it will be probably few for a positive result.

Comment: @CountIblis The boiling will cool it, and as it cools, it will evaporate slower and slower.

Answer (score 1):

It will be the same.

The majority of the effects come from the velocity of the urine going through the urethra, not gravity.  Gravity only takes hold for a fraction of a second, and liquids such as urine typically are broken up by that point so it's no longer a "stream."